# fdisk mkswap No such file or directory

Tags: partition, swap, fdisk

Im trying to create new swap partition but I have error when I try

```
 mkswap /dev/vda1p1
/dev/vda1p1: No such file or directory
```

Please check

```
  -bash-4.2# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda    253:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─vda1 253:1    0 28.1G  0 part /
└─vda2 253:2    0  1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
-bash-4.2# fdisk /dev/vda1
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-59006975, default 2048):
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-59006975, default 59006975): +100M
Partition 1 of type Linux and of size 100 MiB is set

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 82
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'Linux swap / Solaris'

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/vda1: 30.2 GB, 30211571712 bytes, 59006976 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x148f998d

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1p1            2048      206847      102400   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.

WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 22: Invalid argument.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at
the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
Syncing disks.
-bash-4.2# partprobe
-bash-4.2# mkswap /dev/vda1p1
/dev/vda1p1: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
vda    253:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─vda1 253:1    0 28.1G  0 part /
└─vda2 253:2    0  1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Comment: did you try `partx -u /dev/vda1`?

Comment: For more details see partx(8).
-bash-4.2# partx -u /dev/vda1
-bash-4.2# mkswap /dev/vda1p1
/dev/vda1p1: No such file or directory
-bash-4.2# partx -u /dev/vda1p1
partx: stat failed /dev/vda1p1: No such file or directory

Comment: Then have you restarted your machine?

Comment: yes ofcourse i restarted

Comment: Well wait. You are creating the first partition `1`. This already exists. You need to select `3` for your swap partition (if you want another one). You already have `/dev/vda2` configured as swap.